# Which File Is Changed Or Event Is Fired When Something Is Copied To The Clipboard (Ctrl + C)?

Tags: command-line, clipboard

If I'd to hook a function or a program that should execute when the system clipboard content is changed then of which file I've to keep checking or which event is fired and how to catch that event by a programming language? Or a command that can output clipboard content to the terminal so that I can keep running command after short intervals and see if the content has been changed or not.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several frameworks available which support clipboards and such a behavior.

There is for instance [GTK](http://www.gtk.org/) which provides a Gdk Event [GtkClipboard-owner-change](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.2/gtk3-Clipboards.html#GtkClipboard-owner-change) which always gets fired when content in the clipboard has changed. An application can be written in a programming language which supports GTK such as C, [Python](https://wiki.gnome.org/PyGObject) or [Vala](https://live.gnome.org/Vala/).

In Vala following snippet could for instance being used to print to stdout when a clipboard content has changed

```
namespace ClipboardChanged
{
    public static int main (string[] args)
    {
        Gtk.init (ref args);

        Gtk.Clipboard clipboard = Gtk.Clipboard.get(Gdk.SELECTION_CLIPBOARD);
        clipboard.owner_change.connect(() => {
            stdout.printf("Clipboard has changed\n");
        });

        Gtk.main();

        return 0;
    }
}
```

This code snippet can be saved in a text file e.g. clipboard-changed.vala and be compiled with valac with the following command

```
valac --pkg=gtk+-3.0 clipboard-changed.vala
```

Of course for this to work valac needs to be installed

```
sudo apt-get install valac
```

There is only one shortcoming in this though that it only works with the main clipboard but not with primary selection (selection of content with the mouse).

Comment: any possibilities for Java to capture the clipboard change event?

Comment: Being so specific I assume this has not much to do with Ubuntu and might be better asked on stackoverflow.com. This answer here might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484927/listen-to-clipboard-changes-check-ownership

Answer (score 1):

`xclip` is your friend. Look at the manpage for more information, but if you want to set the clipboard (not the selected text), you can use `xclip -sel clip`, then pipe to its stdin to set the clipboard.

There's a `-i filename` parameter to *read* from a file. `-sel` selects the clipboard buffer you want to use. There's `p` (primary, if you select something. It's what middleclick pastes), `clip`, which is the one used with CTRL-C and CTRL-V in all modern desktop environments (QT2 and Emacs 20 use the primary clipboard for some reason).

To get the contents of the clipboard, `xclip -sel clip -o` (prints to stdout). If you want to put it in a file, there's an optional parameter of -o to specify a file to send it to.

I believe there's some information in the manpage to *wait* for when the clipboard changes. I just couldn't decipher it.

Infos here: http://standards.freedesktop.org/clipboards-spec/clipboards-latest.txt

Comment: I haven't read the `xclip` man page. But, the problem about this answer is that if I check the contents of the clipboard to find out when the clipboard is changed and set the time interval, lets say, 500ms then there is still possibility that I would miss a clipboard content if the user quickly copies two different contents within this 500ms time limit. Won't reducing the time limit make it inefficient and more like a hack than a proper approach?